# Kendo UI Autocomplete open link in same tab/window

Tags: kendo-ui

Below example allow us to open a link in a new tab/window when user selects item from the AutoComplete.

http://jsbin.com/EQamewI/2/edit

How to modify `window.open(href)` to open the link in same tab/window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `window.open(href)` use `location.assign(href);`

Documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp

If you are in an iframe, you can use `top.location.assign(href);`